# Alternatives to "intoxicates" in formal writing

Tags: vocabulary, formality

In the following sentence:

> Stephano intoxicates Trinculo and Caliban.

To me, the wording is awkward. I would like to find alternatives to *intoxicates* in formal writing, but I cannot discern what to use in this case without using *to be*.

Comment: You could easily say "Stephano gets Trinculo and Caliban drunk." And good luck with your paper on *The Tempest*.

Comment: Can't mark a comment as answer T_T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go for ***inebriates*** as well.

From [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inebriate)

> **in·e·bri·ate**  (n-br-t)
>
> tr.v. in·e·bri·at·ed, in·e·bri·at·ing, in·e·bri·ates
>
> 1. To make drunk; intoxicate.
> 2. To exhilarate or stupefy as if with alcohol.